# Gecko Javascript to c++

Tags: javascript, c++, callback, gecko

Im using the xulrunner example application and im trying to work out how to call into c++ code from javascript. I have googled and the best i came up with was to use nsIDOMEventListener interface but have no idea how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What C++ code, your code? That's typically done by [creating an XPCOM component in C++](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPCOM_Components).

In the most recent builds (1.9.2, I believe) js-ctypes library is included, which is a simple way to call C functions from JS from a DLL and is similar to ctypes in python and others.

Comment: Can this be done with out making a new dll? I would like to do it via the xulrunner interface.

Comment: I already said what can be done. Your only other option other than creating an XPCOM components is making jsctypes work (possibly by using a new XULRunner) and using it.